# Scaffold and Array type column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have created model, controller and view with rails scaffold generator:

```
rails g scaffold Todo description:string tags:array
```

So I have the model:

```
class Todo
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :description, :type => String
  field :tags, :type => Array
end
```

And controller:

```
def create
    @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])
    @todo.save
```

But this case (auto-generated code) I get error that tells me something like:

```
tags field must be array datatype, but you're trying to use string
```

So I have fixed the controller:

```
def create
    #@todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])

    @tmp = params[:todo]
    @tmp["tags"] = @tmp["tags"].split(',')
    @todo = Todo.new(@tmp)
```

And I'm just wondering if there is any better way to fix my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how your view is structured. From what I see, there must be a single text input or something, into which you input tags, separated by comma. No wonder it comes as a string! In this case your workaround is correct. I would add stripping of leading and trailing whitespace, though.

```
@tmp["tags"] = @tmp["tags"].split(',').map(&:strip)
```

To get a real array in params your HTML must look like this:

```
<input type='text' name='tags[]' />
<input type='text' name='tags[]' />
<input type='text' name='tags[]' />
```

Where each of these inputs holds a single tag.

Comment: Is it possible to setup rails so scaffold generator will generate the set of input tags (as in your example) ?